# Position of AR.js Marker when moved

Tags: aframe, ar.js

```
 <a-marker type='barcode' value='1'>
  <a-entity gltf-model="#tree" scale="2 2 2"></a-entity>
 </a-marker>   
<a-marker type="pattern" url="ows4.patt">
 <a-entity id="1" class="collidable" geometry="primitive: box" collider-check position="-4 -1 -1" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-entity>
</a-marker>
```

When I scan my marker, a model is shown, but how do I check the position/coordinates of the marker and compare it to a pre-defined position. Will raycaster collider function help .?

Comment: a position on the viewport, or around the user ?

Comment: On the viewport